# JSON Array to sqlite in android

Tags: php, android, json, sqlite

I have json object I get from php as the format here

> ```
> [
>  {
> title: "Title 1",
> status: "1",
> category: "123"
>  },
>  {
> title: "Title 2",
> status: "1",
> category: "123"
>  }, ......
> ]
> ```

I got this (JSON Array) in the android and I want to insert it in sqlite, I have the database columns as the json keys
I know we can do something like this but its not fast

> for(int n = 0; n < JSONArray.length(); n++) {
>
> ```
> JSONObject object = JSONArray.getJSONObject(n);
> ```
>
> }

whats the fastest way to do it ? 
thanks

Comment: If you don't need to query the specific columns, I would recommend to store the json as a String in a field, and when needed use Gson to get it as a object

Answer (score 2):

assuming that

- you know how to write an android SQLiteHelper and
- you stored the json response in a `String json` you can then do:

`JSONObject jsonObj  = new JSONObject(json);`

then write a method in your sqlitehelper that does something similar to this:

```
public long insertRecord(JSONObject obj){  
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
   values.put(TITLE, obj.getString("title"));  
   values.put(STATUS, obj.getInt("status"));  
   return database.insert(MY_TABLE, null, values);  
}
```

For more info on how to create an SQLHelper look at [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Comment: thank your for the answer but please I edited the question sorry its Json array not object

Comment: nothing changes really. Iterate the array and pass the objects one by one in the insertRecord function.